# Given real numbers $x,y > 0$, prove that there exist $ n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ (n-1)x \leq y < nx$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Given real numbers $x,y >0$, prove that there exist $n \in \mathbb{Z}$  such that $ (n-1)x \leq y < nx$.

Could anyone give me a hint please?

Comment: Hint: for $x \gt 0\,$, write it as $\;n-1 \le y/x \lt n \,$. If that reminds you of something, then you are done. Otherwise please provide the context, such as what properties of reals and integers you are supposed to know and use.

Comment: Archemidian property? @dxiv

Comment: This might seem pedantic but the doesn't exist one single n where that is true for all x,y.  Instead for every pair of x,y there exists an n.  But for different pairs of x,y it may be a different n.  Anyway...

Comment: @Smart The Archimedean property covers half of it. The least upper bound property should cover the rest. FWIW your question is equivalent to showing that the [greatest integer function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Definition_and_properties) is well defined, for which you can find several references around here and elsewhere.

Comment: Let K be the set of all m so that mx \le y. Is that set non-empty? Is it bounded above? If both are true what can you say about sup K?

Comment: What if $x=0$ and $y=1$?

Comment: Several of the comments have answered the question you asked - but it's not the question you meant to ask. To ask that question you have to move the "for all $x,y$" to right after "Prove that" . The way you wrote it, you have to find $n$ before you know the values of $x$ and $y$, which is clearly impossible. This kind of care in writing is crucial in real analysis.

Comment: Thank you for your advice @EthanBolker

Comment: @fleablood..... sorry I have corrected the question.

Comment: @dxiv  what do u mean by FWIW?

Comment: @Smart FWIW is shorthand for "*for what it's worth*".

Comment: @fleablood  I can say by the supremum property that sup K exist, but why you choose K as you did? what was the intuition behind your choice?

Comment: @MichaelBurr  thank you very much for your hint that shows me that I must put x,y > 0 in the question above.

Comment: Let $k = \sup K$ then there there is an $m \in K$ so that $k - 1 < m \le k < m+1$.  Now consider $mx < (m+1)x$

Comment: My intuition.  It asks you to prove that there is a integer so that $(n-1)x \le y < nx$  So $n-1$ is the largest integer that that when multiplied $x$ is less or equal to Y.  So $n-1$ = $\max ${ all m so that $mx \le y$}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that there is no such $n$ that $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and that $(n-1)x \leq y < nx$ for all such $x,y$ that $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Note that for any such $n$ that $n  \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $(n-1)\cdot 1 \leq n-1 < n\cdot 1$ but we have $(n-1)\cdot 1\leq n+1$ and $n+1 > n\cdot 1$.

Suppose there are some such $x,y$ that $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and that for every such $n$ that $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $(n-1)x > y \geq nx$. Then we can let $n=2$, which gives $x > y \geq 2x$, impossible; so it is true that for all such $x,y$ that $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ there is some such $n$ that $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and that $(n-1)x \leq y < nx$.

Comment: I could not see exactly what is wrong in $(n-1).1 \leq (n-1) < n.1,$ also in concluding the inequality $0>y \geq 0,$ did you assume that $x = 0$?

Comment: The first paragraph provides a counterexample by considering $y = n-1$ and $y = n+1$ with $x = 1$. The second paragraph I committed a typo. Sorry and thank you. I hope now everything turns out right :).